# Avid's Structure sampler - who's building their own multichannel patches?

Tags: avid, sampler

I've used Structure fairly successfully since it first debuted but am having difficulty figuring out how to build my own multichannel patches. When I open up an instance of Structure that is more than two channels (quad, 5.0, 5.1) and build a patch using the LCR panners in the Edit mode, all I get is LR output. I've poked around searching for some other way of panning samples within a patch but haven't found the solution yet.

Anyone out there able to shed some light on this? Thanks -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knew it could be done, but had to look it up.

HD/Applications/Avid/Pro Tools/Documentation/Plug-ins/AIR Virtual Instruments.pdf

Page 191 of the .pdf, 181 of the Guide:

> **Using Structure on Multichannel (Greater-Than- Stereo) Tracks** *-excerpt*
>
> To pan a stereo (or mono) Sampler patch to surround in Structure:
>
> 1. In the Part list, reveal the Patch
>      list for the Part you want to pan to
>      surround.
> 2. From the Patch menu, select Add Part >
>      Tools and select the type of surround
>      panning you want.
>
> For more information about Surround Panning controls, see “Tools (for Surround)” on page 246.

I just threw a "Stereo Surround Panner Basic" on the Sine Wave patch and successfully panned it Ls, Rs, & LFE. It looks like there's about 20+ different panner Tools for different input/output situations. I haven't had a chance to explore it much past that, but this should get you started down the right road.

Comment: @Steve, that's rockin'! Perfect timing too since I'll be building lots of patches today.